# System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException An invalid floating point operation occurred

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the following exception while excecuting this sql command:

```
SELECT (ACOS(SIN(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*SIN(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)+COS(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*COS(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*COS(PI()*13.7910680057092/180.0-PI()*13.7910680057092/180.0))*6371) AS foo
```

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException
>   An invalid floating point operation occurred”

How do I have to change the query to make it run? My approach was

```
ROUND( statement, 2)
```

but it doesn't work.

It's a location search by longitude and latitude

Update: doesn't work with SQL Server 2017 aswell http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/38598

Comment: I'd start with calculating smaller parts of the expression, to find the problem part.

Comment: Round the statement inside `ACOS()` first by, `SELECT (ACOS(ROUND(SIN(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*SIN(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)+COS(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*COS(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*COS(PI()*13.7910680057092/180.0-PI()*13.7910680057092/180.0), 15))*6371) AS foo`

Comment: I think it's because of floating conversation in sql. without rounding, sql server assumes that the input value a little bit bigger than `1`, you can round the input, or subtract a little value like `0.00000000000001` before passing it to acos()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round the statement inside `ACOS()` first

```
SELECT (ACOS( ROUND(SIN(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*SIN(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)+COS(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*COS(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*COS(PI()*13.7910680057092/180.0-PI()*13.7910680057092/180.0), 15))*6371) AS foo
```

it's because of floating conversation in sql. without rounding, sql server assumes that the input value a little bit bigger than 1, you can round the input, or subtract a little value like 0.00000000000001 before passing it to `acos()`

Comment: one last question - why rounding to `15` and not `14` or `16`?

Answer (score 1):

The result for this query is `6371`:

```
SELECT (
SIN(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*SIN(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)+COS(PI()
    *51.0026829600855/180.0)*COS(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*COS(PI()
    *13.7910680057092/180.0-PI()*13.7910680057092/180.0)
)*6371
 AS foo
```

However, `6371` is not eligible for `ACOS`. `ACOS` shoulde be lower or equal to `1`.

For example:

```
SELECT ACOS(1) -- OK
SELECT ACOS(1.1) -- An invalid floating point operation occurred.
```

**UPDATE:**

This query could return a value which is greater than 1. So try to use `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT 
(
ACOS
(
    CASE WHEN      
        (SIN(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*SIN(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)
        +COS(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*COS(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)
        *COS(PI()*13.7910680057092/180.0-PI()*13.7910680057092/180.0)) > 1
        THEN 1
    ELSE      
        (SIN(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*SIN(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)
        +COS(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)*COS(PI()*51.0026829600855/180.0)
        *COS(PI()*13.7910680057092/180.0-PI()*13.7910680057092/180.0)) 
    END 
)
*6371) AS foo
```

Comment: 6371 is outside the `ACOS`

Comment: @Dr.Snail Could you clarify, pls. The result is `6371` and for that value you are applying `ACOS` function.

Comment: I'm not doing `ACOS(1* 6371)` - I do `ACOS(1)*6371`

Comment: @Dr.Snail ooops, thanks for clarifying. It is great that a reason is found. Nevertheless, I updated my reply.